# Changing the theme of the webpage

Tags: html, css, themes

I know this is nowhere related to coding question but before I start working on the scenario I would like to get some guidance.

The scenario is to give the option to change the theme of the page. What I have decided is, give common class for multiple elements like

- **h1 tag for all main titles of the page**
- **.image class for all the images of the page**
- **class for p tag for the content of the page**
- **and so on....**

So I will create multiple stylesheet with these class names with different color.

But the difficulty comes with the positioning of the each elements. I tought of giving inline style to each element to define the position related stuffs. For example

```
.image {border:grey solid 1px /*this border color will be different in each stylesheet*/}

<div class="image" style="float:right; margin:6px"><img src="" /> </div>
```

So like this all other elements will be having inline css for the aligning purpose.

Do you think this is the best way to achieve the theme scenario??

***PS - User has access to customize the theme. (We are giving edit panel). This is not actually web page, it is a product module (Just like how we change the color of the Powepont graphs and charts).***

Comment: Prodeuct module! Is this an HTML,css site or PHP,ASP.Net etc

Comment: @syedmohsin it is not about which language is been used. I am trying to get an idea for implementation. Of-course this is mainly based on css implementation. consider jus like powerpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really... I think you should load a default "blank' theme for the basic styles and general styles. Than load another stylesheet depending on what theme the user has chosen. In that theme you specify the theme-specific styles (like the border-color from your example).

Comment: User has access to customize the theme. so whenever he changes the color it should append the pre-defined color. Just like PowerPoint elements

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or  [SaSS](http://sass-lang.com/) .

LESS works both on server side and client side